# Adding custom border to another application with Win32 API

Tags: c, winapi

I'd like to add my custom border rectangle to another application window like this:

[image]

I wrote this code by surfing from google but didn't help me:

```
HWND hWndX;
HRGN hRegX;
HDC hdc;
hWndX = FindWindow(NULL, "Untitled - Notepad");
hdc = GetDC(hWndX);

if (hWndX)
{
    hRegX = CreateRectRgn(10, 10, 200, 200);
    SetWindowLong(hWndX, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(hWndX, GWL_STYLE));
    SetWindowPos(hWndX, hWndX, 0, 0, 100, 100, SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
    SetWindowRgn(hWndX, hRegX, true);
}
else
    MessageBox(hWndX, "Cant find the window handle", "Error!", 0);
```

Comment: Looks like C. Why the C++ tag?

Comment: You could create a [layered window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx) that you position on top of the other window.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This kind of thing /might/ have worked in the old Win16/Windows 95 era, but these days, the OS protects one program from affecting the other.  To change the border of another process, you will need to inject your code (as a dll) into the other process (assuming you have the correct security level).   It's not that it is impossible,  but it's not the sort of thing a beginner coder would be able to do.

Comment: *"these days, the OS protects one program from affecting the other"* - True. Yet not applicable. You *can* get a device context to a window in another process, without injecting code (exactly like the OP did). Besides, the real solution here would have been a transparent window, that's always on top, that renders the frame around the window underneath it. This answer is not useful.

Comment: @IInspectable - do you have a link to such a thing?

Comment: See the [GetDC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144871.aspx) documentation. Passing `NULL` retrieves a DC of the entire screen. That DC is clearly not owned by the calling process, but still a valid DC that can be used to read from and write to.

Comment: I think the entire screen is a special case.  See this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724291(VS.85).aspx "Handles to GDI objects are private to a process. That is, only the process that created the GDI object can use the object handle. "

Comment: How does that contradict my previous statement? The return value of `GetDC` is private to the process that called it, but still references a USER object (the window), owned by a different process. The entire screen is in no way special.